# Laravel : Check if another user is currently logged in

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm speaking about a simple laravel's 4.2 web site with authentication system.

I am user A (super-user), and I want to see if user B or/and user C (and all other users) are logged in. Is there any built in function (something with Auth class) to do this ?

Comment: You can check how long ago the other users logged in, but it is not possible to be sure if a user is online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say for sure if a user B/C is logged in. But you can guess if a user is logged in. If you remember the last action of user B/C and you know the timeout until a user gets logged out automatically this would give you an estimate value if the user is still logged in or not.

Add a migration for your users table and add a new field to your table

```
$table->timestamp('last_activity')->nullable();
```

Add a before filter

```
App::before(function ($request) {
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $now = new DateTime();
        $user->last_activity = $now->getTimestamp();
        $user->save();
    }
});
```

Now you can check when the last action of user B/C was and if this is within the auto logout time it is possible that the user is still logged in. If not the user is definitely logged out.

In case you want to log users activity there is a package [Regulus343/ActivityLog](https://github.com/Regulus343/ActivityLog).

Comment: What if you have more than 1000 users. Everytime they load or refresh a page, you have to query your database. You're killing your bandwidth and processor if you do that

Answer (score 0):

It's easy but you can only check one person at time which means it's not possible to use complex conditions for example count all logged in users.
If you want to check if a user other than you is logged in, use a helper function like this.

```
<?php 
// Helper.php

    public function isLoggedIn($user_id)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            return $user_id == Auth::user()->id;
        }
    }  

?>
```

Comment: Won't this always result to false for every other user except the user logged in?